# In Dafny can I define a method that maps over sets?

Tags: set, dafny

Hi I can define a function:

```
class Node {
    var next:set<Node> ;
    var name:string;
    constructor(n:string) {
        next := {};
        name :=n;
    }
}
function   stringfunSet(nds:set<Node>) :set<string>
     decreases nds 
     reads nds {       
       if nds=={} then {} else ( var x :| x in nds ; {x.name}+stringfunSet(nds -{x} ))
    }
```

but this is not executable. I have read "Compiling Hilbert's epsilon operator" but know that mapping form set to set is executable. So just need to check that there is no way in Dafny to define a method that mapps over sets:  `(set<A>, A->B) -> set<B>`.
If this is the case dose this mean that sets  are largely used for verification and not for implementation?

Comment: Thanks I have been looking for that all day.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a definition of mapping over a `set` using a comprehension.

```
function method SetMap<A,B>(f: A->B, s: set<A>): set<B>
{
  set x | x in s :: f(x)
}
```